# MySQL Cannot add or update a child row - foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, key, constraints

I've seen countless posts about the same error, usually with the same solutions but that's not the case for me!

I'm working with Magento, and getting a foreign key error when saving a customer address. the error is as follows:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`carltonpackaging`.`customer_address_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_PARENT_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) O)

The data I'm trying to update in the `customer_address_entity` includes a value of 3 for `parent_id`. There is a record in the `customer_entity` table with an `entity_id` of 3.

Both tables are using InnoDB, both `customer_entity.entity_id` and `customer_address_entity.parent_id` are `INT(11)`.

This isn't custom functionality either, this is Magento's core stuff that's playing up - I can't figure out why!

EDIT: Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_address_entity` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity Id',
  `entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type Id',
  `attribute_set_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute Set Id',
  `increment_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Increment Id',
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Parent Id',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Created At',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Updated At',
  `is_active` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Is Active',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_PARENT_ID` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_PARENT_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=874 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customer Address Entity'

CREATE TABLE `customer_entity` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity Id',
  `entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type Id',
  `attribute_set_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute Set Id',
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Website Id',
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Email',
  `group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Group Id',
  `increment_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Increment Id',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Created At',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Updated At',
  `is_active` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Is Active',
  `disable_auto_group_change` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Disable automatic group change based on VAT ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` (`entity_type_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID` (`email`,`website_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_WEBSITE_ID_CORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=875 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customer Entity'
```

EDIT: Despite sending a `parent_id` of 3, MySQL was receiving a `parent_id` of 0, causing the error. Haven't yet figured out why this is, but I'll update when I do!

Comment: Can you get the actual SQL statement that is sent to the server?

Comment: Table definitions and Sql statement.Better yet a fiddle.

Comment: I can't get the whole SQL statement easily as it's using Magento's EAV structure, and I've no idea how to dig the statement out!

I can get the table definitions, will edit my original question

Comment: So, you finally found how to get the statement :)

Comment: I did :) Never thought of using MySQL's general query log! Doh! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try testing your queries directly on your database first. Mostly, constraint errors are thrown when you're trying to call/write a foreign key that doesn't exist, or you're trying to delete one that is still existing/needed on the other tables.

Comment: I can't do that easily, it uses Magento's database class (Zend) and I've no clue how deep that goes between about 6 tables in this case!

EDIT: However, I can try to just update one column in this table I guess - not the exact same query but it's worth a shot!

Comment: I just ran UPDATE customer_address_entity SET updated_at=NOW(), parent_id=3 WHERE entity_id=2; and it worked just fine... now it makes even less sense as to why it fails!

Comment: Are you using Mysql? Aren't there a few IDEs available where you can see the data that are being written by the Magento program through the .sql file?

Comment: I am, and I don't know - however you triggered me to realise I'm running on my local machine, so I enabled the general query log, tail'd it and found it's using a parent_id of 0, not 3! No clue why but it is! Sure enough, copying and pasting the query directly into my SQL client produces the same error, as there is no customer_entity record with an entity_id of 0.

Comment: Great! That way you can assume that you're passing the wrong parameter to the sql. You can continue your error finding from there. Good luck!

Comment: Exactly that! I was passing the right value to the model, but I then had an event observer that was changing this value back to it's original value... or so I thought - turns out, the original value was empty (shouldnt have been) so it was setting it to null (the numeric equivalent being 0). Commented out that line in my observer, no more problem!

2 days! 2 whole days!